# How to change dismissible boolean of modalBottomSheet in flutter after its displayed

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet, dismissible

I am showing a bottomsheet in flutter by default the `isDismissible = false` dismissible is set to false but based on certain conditions i want to change this to true i have tried passing a bool to `showModalBottomSheet` method and changing its value from inside the child widget using setState method but its not working. Any help would be really appreciated.

below is my code for showing bottomsheet

```
openBottomDialog<T extends StateStreamableSource<Object?>>(
{required BuildContext context,
required Widget child,
double? height,
Function? onClose,
bool? dismissible,
Function? onStateChange}) {
return showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  barrierColor: AppColors.of(context).semiTransparentBackgroundColor,
  backgroundColor: AppColors.of(context).semiTransparentBackgroundColor,
  isScrollControlled: true,
  isDismissible: dismissible ?? false,
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(24.r))),
  builder: (model) {
    return BlocProvider.value(
        value: BlocProvider.of<T>(context),
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 8, sigmaY: 8),
          child: Wrap(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: AppColors.of(context).d15151AwF5F5F5,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(24.r),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(24.r))),
                // margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        AppAsset(
                          key: const Key('close_bottom_sheet'),
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                            onClose!();
                          },
                          asset: AppImages.line,
                          tintColor:
                              AppColors.of(context).bottomSheetHandleColor,
                        ),
                        Container(child: child)
                      ],
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  });
 }
```

the child widget is a state full widget and inside that i am using setState method to update this variable.

```
            setState(() {
              widget.dismissible = false;
              countdownTimer.cancel();
              sliderState = SlideState.loading;
            });
```